# Sending PL/SQL block to db using OCI always return rows_affected=1 (ORACLE DB)

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am writing a client in C which sends a query to Oracle DB, and when I try to sample the number of rows affected by it, I always get value of 1.
This is the query:

```
char * query =    "BEGIN "\
                  "INSERT INTO table_name ( field_1, field_2, id, field_3 ) VALUES ( :1, :2, :3, 1 );"\
                  "EXCEPTION "\
                  "when dup_val_on_index then "\
                  "UPDATE table_name SET field_1 =:4, field_2 =:5, field_3 = 1 where id = :6 and field_4 <= :7;"\
                  "END; ";
```

I execute it using `OCIStmtExecute` function of OCI with `OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS`, and in order to sample the affected rows I do:

```
ub4 update_count;
OCIAttrGet(stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, &update_count, 0, OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT, ctx->hp);
```

For some weird reason update_count is always 1.
It's odd because if I send a simple Update or Insert query exatcly the same way, I get the correct result in update_count.

Is there anything that should be done diffrently when executing the query in this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately how things work. Your block could be deleting 20 rows, then updating 10, etc. SQL%ROWCOUNT always returns 1 after successful execution of a PL/SQL block run via execute immediate. You might consider calling SQL%ROWCOUNT inside the dynamic block and then return that value and use it.

You can see this behavior in my trivial LiveSQL script: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kdh6dang21mt8eumn4x6wv0ct

```
begin 
   execute immediate 'begin null; end;'; 
   dbms_output.put_line ('count = ' || sql%rowcount); 
end;   
/


count = 1
```